# C++ output stream to a file is not working

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

My code is below. The buffer has the data but fout2.write does not do anything. The file is created and it is empty.

```
ofstream fout2(fname, ios::binary);
fout2.open(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
if (fout2.is_open()) {
    //problem is here   //write the buffer contents
    fout2.write(rmsg.buffer, rmsg.length);
    fout2.flush();
    memset(rmsg.buffer, 0, sizeof(rmsg.buffer)); //clear the buffer
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: using only ofstream fout2(fname, ios::binary) the if statement always returned false... so i added fout2.open(...

Comment: Try `ofstream fout2(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);`

Comment: It didn't work as well

Comment: It should work the same. The arguments to the constructor are treated the same as calling `open`.

Comment: It workedd!!!.. I removed the fout2.open and kept only fout2(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out) .. can you post it as an answer so I can accept.. also can you explain to me what was wrong? was I opening the file twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to do both input and output, as implied by your use of `ios::in`, you should use `fstream`, not `ofstream`. Then you should pass all the open modes in the constructor, and you don't need to call `open()`.

```
fstream fout2(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to close the file. You may either do it by

```
fout2.close()
```

Or by simply closing the scope of the fout2:

```
{
    ofstream fout2(fname, ios::binary);
    fout2.open(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    if (fout2.is_open()) {
         fout2.write(rmsg.buffer, rmsg.length);
         //out2.flush(); // no need for this
         memset(rmsg.buffer, 0, sizeof(rmsg.buffer)); //clear the buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the point of `out2.flush()`? That should send the buffer to the file, even if it's not closed.

Comment: I tried without the flush() and with it .. I also close the file and the scope.. nothing works... the file just gets created with 0 bytes!

Comment: In [Haya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1781150/haya-raed) case flush() is the syntactic salt, it will be called anyway when the fout2 destructor will be called

Comment: No it was 51 when I was testing